# tabs in javascript resetting

Tags: javascript

Sorry this is probably stupid wood for trees stuff but:

All I want is a `div` with a couple of links - you click on the links and you switch to another `div`. Standard tab stuff.  That's it. But when I run the code below, it switches to the `div` I want then resets straight back to the original div.  Why?

the Javascript:

```
number_of_pages = 4;  
function cyber(page)
{  
    for(i = 1; i <= number_of_pages; i++)  
    {  
        off = 'monitor' + i;  
        document.getElementById(off).style.display = 'none';  
    }  
    on = 'monitor' + page;  
    document.getElementById(on).style.display = 'block';  

    alert(on); //debug  
}
```

the CSS:

```
.monitor{width: 400px; border: 1px solid #333; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px}
```

the HTML:

```
<div class="monitor" id="monitor1" style="display: block">  
<a href="" onclick="cyber(2)">foo</a><br />  
<a href="" onclick="cyber(3)">bah</a><br />  
</div>  

<div class="monitor" id="monitor2" style="display: none">
<a href="" onclick="cyber(1)">homepage</a>
</div>
```

etc...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit and fix markup, select code blocks and click the code button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the browser is actually following the `href=""` directive, which is to reload the current page, immediately after it executes the javascript. You need to `return false` on the `onclick` handler to prevent browser from obligating to the `href`:

```
number_of_pages = 4;  
function cyber(page)
{  
    for(i = 1; i <= number_of_pages; i++)  
    {  
        off = 'monitor' + i;  
        document.getElementById(off).style.display = 'none';  
    }  
    on = 'monitor' + page;  
    document.getElementById(on).style.display = 'block';  

    alert(on); //debug

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Gentlemen you remain the single most valuable people I'm aware of on the Internet, thank you very very kindly. And thank you whoever corrected my post. I am learning :)